# Email and IP String preprocessing for classification task

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, dataset

I am relatively new to the field of data-science, pardon my novice question. What are the available methods to convert `email` and `ip` to vectors for online learning algorithms. The classification aim is to assess fraud/non fraud transactions. As continues explanation: the other relevant fields are categorical and they have been vectorised.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68441/application-of-lsa-lsi-is-it-common-to-include-the-use-of-an-edit-distance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a really interesting question! String vectorization is an area of active research right now, and a there's a ton of interesting approaches out there.

First of all, ip addresses are hierarchical, and can be split by decimals into 4 categorical variables, each with 256 levels (watch out for IPv4 vs IPv6 though)!  In a linear model, you can use the top level ip block directly, perhaps interacted with the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th block depending on how much data you have.  In a tree-based model (e.g. a random forest or GBM), try converting the ip address to an integer and modeling it directly.  A random forest or GBM should be able to identify interesting blocks of the ip range for your model. Most databases have functions to do this conversion, and I know there's a [really good R package too.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iptools/index.html)

For email addresses, start by splitting on the @ symbol into address, domain.  Domain is probably useful on it's own as a categorical variable, but you might want to further add a variable for .com vs .edu vs .gov, etc. (The [urltools package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/index.html) can help you extract top-level domains— someone really needs to write an `emailtools` package!)  For the address part (the bit before the @ symbol), you could use a character n-gram vectorizer to create a very wide, very sparse matrix which you can then use directly in your model, or can further process using something like SVD to reduce it's dimensionality.  You could also try a word vectorizer, splitting on symbols like `.`, `-`, and `_`.

There's a TON of information in those 2 fields— good luck extracting it!

---

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory answer. Prior posting this question I did some lookaround and found locality preserving hash functions. I persued the approach after reading a few papers and the major limitation is the huge signatures they generate. Is the LSH approach an overkill/dead ally for my scenario?

Comment: @Segmented I've never actually tried LSH.  For IP addresses, converting them to integers and putting them in a GBM has worked really well for me in the past (the integer representation preserves the locality of ip addresses really well).  For email addresses, splitting out domain and then character - ngrams has also worked, but is a bit difficult to implement.  Maybe try something simple first and see what your results are like?

Comment: thank you for patiently explaining. I am accepting your answer as it defines a clear methodology to approach such a problem.

Comment: @Segmented Glad I could help!